# Unix - substitution

Tags: regex, unix

i have problem with substitution. I have a file with 1 line of random characters with brackets "{}" around 1 character. I want to move with these brackets on the previous character or on the next one. (I know how to do it if the line of character is still, non-changing.) But I wonder how to do it when I don't know these chars and I don't know where these brackets are.

For Example: " ABC123{X}CBA321 " ==> " ABC12{3}XCBA321 " or " ABC123X{C}BA321 "

I would like to use awk or sed, some regex, maybe...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move backward one character:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\){\(.\)}/{\1}\2/g' file
```

Move forward one character:

```
sed -e 's/{\(.\)}\(.\)/\1{\2}/g' file
```

To modify the file in-place, use the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(.\){\(.\)}/{\1}\2/g' file
sed -i -e 's/{\(.\)}\(.\)/\1{\2}/g' file
```

The first example works by matching any character followed by a character surrounded by `{}`.  Without grouping, this is: `.{.}`  We add grouping so we can put the two characters in the output.  Instead of surrounding the second character with `{}` with surround the first character.  This is `{\1}\2`.

The second example works similarly, but matches `{.}.` first then outputs `\1{\2}`.

Comment: @Tomblin, I used cat as an example to show the data could be piped.  @ashawley shows a better example of this.

Answer (score 3):

This will move the brackets to the previous character:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\){\(.\)}/{\1}\2/g' < in_file > out_file
```

This will move the brackets to the next character:

```
sed -e 's/{\(.\)}\(.\)/\1{\2}/g' < in_file > out_file
```

Comment: Wow, I beat you by four seconds.  And we have the exact same regexp.  xD

Comment: @strager,davr: You both had shorter regexps, but I don't think the "g" modifier is unnecessary.

Comment: Awesome. You guys are pretty fast :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small example.

```
$ echo "ABC123{X}CBA321" | sed -e 's/\(.\){\(.\)}\(.\)/{\1}\2\3/'
ABC12{3}XCBA321
$ echo "ABC123{X}CBA321" | sed -e 's/\(.\){\(.\)}\(.\)/\1\2{\3}/'
ABC123X{C}BA321
```

Here's how to edit the file in place with sed.

```
$ sed -i -e 's/\(.\){\(.\)}\(.\)/{\1}\2\3/' file
$ sed -i -e 's/\(.\){\(.\)}\(.\)/\1\2{\3}/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried in perl. this will move the bracket to the previous character

```
my $a="ABC123{X}CBA321";

if ($a =~ /(.)\{(.)\}/)
        {
                print "$`"."{$1}";
                print "$2";
                print "$'";
        }
```

NOTE: $` is string before the match & $' is string after match

Comment: I did escape , but not sure why it was not reflected in my post.Thank you